# Get Unicode version of a codepoint in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a small script printing some debug infos of unicode characters. I need to filter out everything that came with Unicode 8.0 because of compatibility.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unicodedata

skip = [
    0x0001F643, # Unicode 8.0
    0x0001F644, # Unicode 8.0
]

for n in range(0x0001F600, 0x0001F64F):
    if n in skip:
        continue

    c = chr(n)
    name = unicodedata.name(c)
    print('{} U+{:5X} {}'.format(c, n, name))
```

Is there a way to get the Unicode version in which a specific codepoint was added programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) contains and provides some property information about Unicode characters, but unfortunately  [Age](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-6.html#Age) is not one of them. You will need to download and parse [`DerivedAge.txt`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/DerivedAge.txt) for the UCD if you want access to this information.

Comment: Great, thanks. The link speaks of unicode property regular expressions like `\p{age=3.0}`. I tried to get this running using the regex module. But `print(regex.compile(r'[\p{age=8.0}]').match("ö"))` gives me strange compile errors. Any idea how to utilize regular expressions for that?

Comment: `re` doesn't support Unicode properties. [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports some Unicode properties, but not Age. You will need to use the UCD directly to get what you want.